# Complexity Class theorization

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Being C a complexity class, if C is contained in its complementary class, does it imply that the C = coC?

So far I tried to prove $C \subseteq coC \implies C \subseteq coC \land coC \subseteq C$.

I can assume that  $C \subseteq coC$, but how can I prove that $coC \subseteq C$?

---

I came up with this:

$ L \in coC \rightarrow     \overline{L} \in C \rightarrow \overline{L} \in coC \rightarrow L \in C$

We know that $\overline{L} \in C \rightarrow \overline{L} \in coC$ because $C \subseteq coC$

Thus :

$C = coC \rightarrow C\subseteq coC \land coC \subseteq C$

The theorem is proved

Comment: Hint: What can you say about cocoC?

Comment: cocoC should be equivalent to C if I'm not mistaken, isn't my proof right?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.